# Using shadow with borderRadius on a react native component

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I'm trying to set a shadow on a custom card component in React Native with a borderRadius property of 10.

Here is the code:

```
borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
shadowOffset: {
  width: 0,
  height: 3, 
},
elevation: 3,
```

How can I apply rounded corners to the shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shadowRadius property to shape the rounded corners. But this will only work for iOS since Android only takes the elevation property to create shadows. You can read more about this in the official documentation here. https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props

You can have styles like this example below applied to the container view of your custom card.

```
 const shadowsStyling = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 0
    }
}
```